# Is `sauce_whisk` gem compatible with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails, capybara-webkit, saucelabs

I am running a rails application and having my test cases written in capybara.
I need to run all those with sauce labs.
I tried using sauce_whisk but those written in capybara are not working.

`....
it "should google", :run_on_sauce => true do
  visit "http://google.com"
end
...` does not works

while

`...
it "should google too", :run_on_sauce => true do
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "http://google.com"
end
...` works.

Can anybody help out in this matter ?
I followed this link : https://docs.saucelabs.com/tutorials/ruby/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example a couple working implementations of using sauce_whisk with Capybara.

Here is a simple example using Capybara with RSpec:

```
jobname = scenario.full_description
sessionid = ::Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.session_id
::Capybara.current_session.driver.quit

job = SauceWhisk::Jobs.fetch sessionid
job.name = jobname
job.save

if scenario.exception
  SauceWhisk::Jobs.fail_job sessionid
else
  SauceWhisk::Jobs.pass_job sessionid
end
```

And a slightly more complicated implementation using Cucumber:

```
require "capybara/cucumber"
require "selenium/webdriver"
require 'sauce_whisk'

Around do |scenario, block|
  block.call
  sessionid = ::Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.session_id
  ::Capybara.current_session.driver.quit

  jobname = "#{scenario.feature.name} - #{scenario.name}"

  job = SauceWhisk::Jobs.fetch sessionid
  job.name = jobname
  job.passed = scenario.passed? ? true : false
  job.save
end

Before do | scenario |
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    capabilities = {
      :version => "48.0",
      :browserName => "chrome",
      :platform => "OS X 10.11"
    }

    url = "http://<username>:<access_key>@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub".strip
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
                                   :browser => :remote, :url => url,
                                   :desired_capabilities => capabilities)
  end
  Capybara.default_wait_time = 10
  Capybara.current_driver = :selenium

  job = SauceWhisk::Jobs.fetch ::Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.session_id
  job.name = "#{scenario.feature.name} - #{scenario.name}"
  job.save
end
```

Source:

https://github.com/saucelabs-sample-test-frameworks?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=Capybara